# Can't load jQuery locally in node-webkit app

Tags: node-webkit

I get the following error in my console:

```
Failed to load resource file:///var/folders/n7/94blrknd6639zt8ngcfp9l4m0000gn/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.RRLqW8/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js
```

index.html loads it with:

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I didn't include the `-r` in my zip command to recursively add sub-directories...so it missed everything in ./js.